# Anti Virus automatic update problem with linux squid proxy

Tags: linux, windows-xp, squid, anti-virus, automatic-updates

I am using RHEL 5 linux server with 10 Windows XP client machines,

I installed bit defender internet security 2009 in my windows machines,

My Problem is automatic updates are not performing,

I get following error

[image]

I can't find what i want to do changes in my proxy.

I am using squid 2.6 stable

When i use Norton , get same error.

What i want to do, for update it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havent said anything about how the clients use Squid. Is it a transparent proxy, or do you set the Proxy information in each clients browser?

Either way: See if your Antivirus software has a configure option for Proxy usage. They usually do.